# Append powershell script line into file .bat

Tags: powershell

I want to append a single powershell script command into a file .bat

I've tried using pipe, but i've append oly output and i don't need it.

for example i have this line in a foreach cycle and i want all line into a file that is in \test\file.bat path.

```
Netsh.exe advfirewall firewall ad rule name=$myname ecc
```

It is possible directly in powershell?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$names = "Name1","Name2","Name3"

foreach($myname in $names)
{
    "Netsh.exe advfirewall firewall ad rule name=$myname ecc" |
        Out-File .\file.bat -Append
}
```

If you need to execute the command in the PowerShell script as well as write it to the BAT file, then you can do something like this instead:

```
foreach($myname in $names)
{
    $cmd = "Netsh.exe advfirewall firewall ad rule name=$myname ecc"

    Invoke-Expression $cmd

    $cmd | Out-File .\file.bat -Append
}
```